# How decode QR code image from preview android?

Tags: android, android-camera, qr-code, zxing

I initialized the camera and I start it into preview mode. For the preview I take the source code from http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html

Now I want decode the QR code with zxing library from the preview, but I haven't any idea as to do..
Can you hlep me?

Answer (score 1):

if you want decode QR code with zwing, you need to use this 2 classes :

```
IntentIntegrator.java
IntentResult.java
```

Call the Intent like this in your Activity:

```
IntentIntegrator intentScan = new IntentIntegrator(this);
Collection<String> desiredBarcodeFormat = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Arrays.asList("QR_CODE"));
intentScan.initiateScan();
```

You receive the result in your Activity with this method :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (scanResult != null)
               String out = scanResult.getContents();
        }
    }
}
```

Link to documentation :

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Link to classes :

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/

Comment: To add to Skies answer. Details of this method can be found on the zxing wiki here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent and the code for the IntentIntegrator and IntentResult classes here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/

Comment: Thanks, but if I use those class, I must install the Barcode Scanner apllication, and I wouldn't install any other app. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If there is a solution without install any other app, I'm interested.

Comment: So, do you tell me that there isn't any way to decode without other app? right?

Comment: I never looking for so I don't know.